# show local json data from collection in backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, underscore.js, backbone-views, backbone.js-collections

I have a local json file. I need to put these data in a `Backbone.Collection`, then receive this collection in a `Backbone.View` and render the data in a template. So I tried many ways but...

Model:

```
define([
    'backbone',
], function(Backbone) {
    var InfoModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
            id               : "",
            name             : "",
            info             : "",
            img              : "",
            user             : "",
            userlvl          : "",
            mobile           : "",
            phone            : "",
            fax              : "",
            web              : "",
            email            : "",
            linkedin         : "",
            instagram        : "",
            twitter          : "",
            storeService     : "",
            departomanService: "",
            shopBalence      : "",
            shopWithdrawal   : "",
            shopDeposit      : ""
        } 
    }); 
    return InfoModel;
});
```

Collection:

```
define([
    'backbone',
    'core/application',
    'components/persian_social_tinet/models/information',
], function(Backbone, Application,InfoModel) {
    var InfoCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model : new InfoModel(), 

        url   : function(){
            return 'json!data/' + Application.current_section + '/information.json';
        },

        parse: function(Response){
            return Response;
        }
    });
    return InfoCollection;
});
```

View:

```
define([
    'backbone',
    'components/persian_social_tinet/collections/information',
    'text!components/persian_social_tinet/tpls/leftpanel-acc.html',
], function(Backbone, InfoColl, accTpl ) {
    var accView = Backbone.View.extend({
        className: 'account-leftPanel',
        
        initialize: function() {
            var infoColl = new InfoColl();
            this.listenTo(InfoColl, "sync", this.render) 
        },
       
        render: function() {
            this.template = _.template(accTpl);  
            var item = { infoColl: this.infoColl.toJSON }
            this.$el.html(this.template(item));
            return this;
        }
          
    });
    return accView;
});
```

I want to fetch the collection. However, the json data are not from a server but from the local filesystem.
Please help me.

Comment: Where is the problem, is the request actually successful?

Comment: I can't get json data from collection

Comment: Model should be like this: `model: InfoModel,` apart from that, is the request successfull in network tab? is the `parse` method of collection being invoked?

Comment: I want to get values from the Json file and display them in a template. But when defining a collection, it does not show any value for me to fetch. But Json information is displayed on the network

Comment: Model and collection files are separate, not in one file

Comment: `model  :new InfoModel()` this is wrong syntax. You should pass constructor there not an instance

Comment: When you write that the json data are not from a server but from the local filesystem, do you mean that these data are fixed in your source code? Do you want to avoid using a network request to fetch the data? Is your application by itself hosted in a web server? Please clarify.

Comment: my appliction  is my local system. I want get data from json and show them in browser